# How to minify Assets in yii2 in basic template?

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I am using yii2 basic template. How can I minify the Asset Bundle of my page? I found some documentation regarding minification on http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html but was not able to do so.

Comment: Did you read the part of documentation starting from here? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#an-example I personally prefer using Grunt or similar task runners.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it either [as described in official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) using Yii assets management or by using external asset manager such as Grunt or Gulp.

You can read about how to configure Grunt here: https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/structure-asset-processing-with-grunt.md